In Electron, how do I reverse the maximization of the window?
I am trying to implement maximize and reverse maximize (back to the size before) in Electron but nor sure how to get it to work. Maximize works fine, but reversing it doesn't.
This is what I have.
In my main process I have these two
ipcMain.on("maximize-window", () => {
  const window = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
  if (window) window.maximize();
});

ipcMain.on("unmaximize-window", () => {
  const window = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
  if (window) window.restore();
});

Then in preload I expose them like so
maximizeWindow: () => ipcRenderer.send("maximize-window"),
unmaximizeWindow: () => ipcRenderer.send("unmaximize-window"),

Then in my renderer, in the component with the icons I have it set like so
  const [isMaximized, setIsMaximized] = useState(false);

  const handleMaximize = () => {
    window.electron.maximizeWindow();
    setIsMaximized(true);
  };

  const handleUnmaximize = () => {
    window.electron.unmaximizeWindow();
    setIsMaximized(false);
  };

And on the button I call one of these based on the current state.
  <button
    onClick={isMaximized ? handleUnmaximize : handleMaximize}
    className="w-5 h-5 cursor-pointer flex items-center justify-center no-drag"
  >
    <FaRegSquare className="h-3 w-3 text-black" />
  </button>

But as I've said, the reversing doesn't seem to do anything. How do I get it to work? Do I have to store the size before maximizing then manually set it? Is there no way to just restore it to the state before maximizing?

You should use the unmaximize method instead of restore.
